# Simplify if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function with lot of variables passed into it and I need to create an object of it. How can I simplify this code?

```
obj_in = dict()

if foo:
    obj_in['foo'] = foo
if bar:
    obj_in['bar'] = bar
if john:
    obj_in['john'] = john
```

**UPD:**
My current idea is:

```
fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'john']
obj_in = dict()

for field in fields:
    val = locals()[field]
    if val:
        enrich_dict(field, val, obj_in)


def enrich_dict(field: str, val, obj_in: dict):
    obj_in[field] = val
```

But not really sure of using locals.

Comment: Whats wrong with the code as it is? what is `obj_in` for?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry, fixed it

Comment: @Sayse I have bunch of fields, more then 3, so code looks heavy

Comment: I think the real question is why all these fields are in ``locals`` to begin with. Where are you getting them from? Why are they sometimes not worth keeping?

Comment: What are the mystery objects you're putting in the lookup? Do they have `__str__` methods which you could get the names from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Your current idea seems a whole lot more complicated than the if statements way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: why make a function to put stuff in a dictionary and nothing else instead of just put in dictionary directly?

Answer (score 2):

If you need all the parameters and their values from inside the scope of a function, you should use `locals()`. It will capture the variables in the current scope. If you want the values **before** you modify them in the function, then call `locals` at the beginning of the function, otherwise call it at the end.

```
def func(x, y, z):
    d = locals()
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
    return d, (x, y, z)

func(11, 12, 13)

>>> ({'x': 11, 'y': 12, 'z': 13}, (1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind verbose calls, you can change

```py
def f(foo, bar, john)
```

to

```py
def f(**kwargs)
```

and then directly use that `kwargs` dict in the function

Comment: This is the problem. I have to describe each field: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/657

Comment: Not only does this make the code unmaintainable, you also change the meaning of the code, imagine `foo` is `0` and that is an invalid input, your code now allows that.

Comment: @Sayse not necessarily, just `if kwargs['foo'] == 0: return` or did I miss something?

Comment: @D.Make Could you explain this in a bit more detail? What should I look at in that issue? And what exactly do you mean by "describe each field"? My answer only concerns the function arguments, not fields

Comment: @Matiiss - What would be the point in changing it if you're just going to do that?

Comment: @Sayse in case of variable number of arguments, but I guess that default values could be used then instead, right now I really see just one use case and that would be with classes and inheritance so yes, there is no point to do that here, also OP hasn't made it clear enough about the circumstances